# Ranking system for multiple data

Tags: arrays, laravel, group-by, ranking

Hello everybody I'm engaged to implement a ranking system for cycling I'd like to calculate a rider's rank among the others, here is my sample table :

Results table

```
id     rider_id     point

1       2           100
2       2           50
3       5           200
4       5           60
```

How can I get their **POSITION** based on sum points for each rider
I tried this code but could not get index as a position !

```
      $result=Result::orderBy('point', 'desc')->get();
        $Rider=$result-> groupBy('rider_id')
            ->map(function ($row) {
                return $row->sum('point');
            });
```

The above code gives me this out put :

```
{
"5":260,
"1":150
}
```

okay,so what is the position ? I need the index I think ? what is ranking for rider_id 1 ?

Comment: Which laravel version are u using? Within the version `8.13` you could do something like: `Rider::withSum('results', 'point ')`. Where `results` is an relation in your Rider model. https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/34965

Comment: I'm using laravel 7

Comment: Oh nvm, I see your function works. If you just order the result by the total points you have your ranking? After sorting, the first row is the first rider, the second row the second rider, etc ...

Comment: my problem is how to get index of each result as position !

Comment: Well you can search your ordered rider/result list by using `->search(function ($item) { $item->rider_id === (your rider id) })` The result of search is an index so `+ 1` for your ranking. If you want a list you should do this in a map, so it's O(n2) speed, which is not really fast.

Comment: @tom this does not work because $item is not an object which is included 'rider_id'

I figured it out by a complicated code I think !
I convert the result toArray() and 
apply this code :
array_search($id, array_keys($user)) + 1 ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by a complicated code I think !
I converted the result toArray() and apply this code :

```
array_search($id, array_keys($user)) + 1 ;
```

I'm pretty sure it's not an Laravel optimized code
I think I would use to better collection like SEARCH !
Any Ideas !